# How to stop overlapping Canvas image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BadVr.jpg)

I want the image to appear when the command related to it is execute, but insted am getting this, the image remains there when different command related to image is executed, and it feel kind of untiedy overlaped.

HERES THE CODE.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
w=Tk()
w.geometry('800x400')
nam=Label(w,text="name of car")
nam.place(x=130,y=50) 
w.configure(bg='#b000ff')
le2=Label(w,text="NUMBER",bg='#6863f6',fg='black',font='comicsansms 10 bold')le2.place(x=0,y=180)
ent2=Entry(w,textvar=StringVar,bg='white',fg='black')
ent2.place(x=70,y=180)
lo = Image.open('F:\\all net downoades\\audier.png')
vo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(lo)
lo4 = Image.open('F:\\all net downoades\\lambo.png')
vo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(lo4)
def one():
    cn = Canvas(w, widt=400, height=250)  # n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, or center
    cn.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=E)
    cn.create_image(200,135,image=vo)
#another func
def two():
    cn6 = Canvas(w, widt=400, height=250)  # n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, or center
    cn6.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=E)
    cn6.create_image(200,135,image=vo2)
def both():
    if int(ent2.get()) == 1:
        one()
    elif int(ent2.get()) == 2:
        two()
    else:
        pass
bui=Button(w,text="ok",command=both)
bui.place(x=0,y=100)
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `cn.pack_forget()` when new image show up

Comment: can you guide me in which line i should write this cn.pack_forget()??

Comment: On top of the function where you want to hide the previous image

Comment: am sorry am so confuse could you elaborate little more?

Comment: ive added an answer

Comment: You can create the canvas and image once, then update the image inside `one()` or `two()`.  BTW, why don't you use just a `Label` to replace the canvas if you just want to show an image?

Comment: This code is working but when am increasing the function like def three() and def four() then this code is not working. And also am not getting the code from if count>1

Comment: @acw1668 can you give me a few line example

Comment: I have added an answer for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create new canvas whenever `one()` or `two()` is called.  You should create the canvas once and hide it initially, then update the image inside the canvas and show it inside `one()` or `two()` functions:

```
def one():
    cn.itemconfigure('image', image=vo)

def two():
    cn.itemconfigure('image', image=vo2)

...
cn = Canvas(w, width=400, height=250, bg='#b000ff', highlightthickness=0)
cn.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=E)
cn.create_image(200, 135, image=None, tag='image')

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: as being a beginner  can you please elaborate me why you wrote tag=“image” am not getting it.

Comment: It just associates a *tag* (like an ID in string) to the canvas image item.  You can also use the id returned by `cn.create_image(...)`, like `image_item = cn.create_image(...)`, then use `itemconfigure(image_item, ...)`.  Using *tag* is more convenient when you want to refer to a group of canvas items if you assign the same *tag* to the group of items.

Comment: Thanks for the swift  explication.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this and let me know

```
count = 0
def one():
    global cn,count
    count+=1
    if count >1:
        cn6.pack_forget()
    cn = Canvas(w, widt=400, height=250)  # n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, or center
    cn.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=E)
    cn.create_image(200,135,image=vo)
#another func
def two():
    global cn6,count
    count+=1
    if count > 1:
        cn.pack_forget()
    cn6 = Canvas(w, widt=400, height=250)  # n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, or center
    cn6.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=E)
    cn6.create_image(200,135,image=vo2)
```